# How do I create shapes and place them in any positions with <hr>?

Tags: html, eclipse

I'm trying to make a house using hr tags, but I've soon discovered that I can't put square shapes(as windows) inside any certain hr-tag-made rectangle/square I've created, they always stack.

Is there a way to use positioning to manually place the shapes?

Comment: i am suggesting you that you can use PATH tag for this. read the link below :http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
<hr class="abc"></hr>

.abc{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;

}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLkdfa34/)